# How to create a time lapse video from a bunch of photos?

Tags: macos, photos

How to create a time lapse video similar to this one with OSX:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zfcgzqgdLUY

I have all the photos I just need some help creating it?  Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a Mac?  Well, it should have come with iMovie, which is part of the iLife package.  using iMovie, you can simply drag and drop the images from the folder they are in, onto the editing time line.  Space them out according to how fast you want them to display, drag and drop a song onto the audio portion of the time line, and export it as a movie.
[iMovie'11](http://www.apple.com/ilife/imovie/)

Comment: Do you know how to remove the default zooming of the images?

Comment: According to Apple, zooming isn't a default, but rather an effect that can be applied to change the feel of the movie.  iMovie should NOT be zooming in on any of the images.  Make sure you are not cropping any of the images you add, as this will give the impression of Zooming.  Try selecting the images you add, and ensuring No Effect have been applied.

Comment: Tried that doesn't work.  I simply added a bunch of equally sized images and then it creates the zoom in zoom out event as a transition

Comment: Hmm...Well..."In iMovie, choose File > New Project.

The File menu appears in a light gray bar across the top of your computer screen.


To apply a theme to your project, select one of the themes presented below Project Themes.

If you don’t want to add any theme-based elements to your project, select No Theme."  So make sure you are not selecting a theme for your project.  It is entirely possible that the theme being applied to your project is also applying the transition between images.  They cover adding and removing transitions here http://support.apple.com/kb/PH2115

Comment: As suggested by others here iMovie has big issues working with a large amount of images. Anything above 1000 images or so and it seems like it can't handle it. I'm using a MacBook Pro 15" w/TouchBar and iMovies crashes or halts completely for a VERY long time. I'd recommend using the `Time Lapse Assembler" instead as proposed in: https://superuser.com/a/1035473/104737

Comment: There appears to be a Ken Burns Cropping style applied by default to images. Click in the timeline area and select all images (Command + A), click the Cropping icon in the top right, and select a different Style: Fit or Crop to Fill.

Answer (score 18):

On any platform, including OSX, use the image toolkit that comes with [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) to convert a series of images to a video with this command:

```
convert *.jpg myvideo.mpeg
```

The images should have a unique numeric sequence number for a prefix, either the time of the image or simply _001 etc. (like cap_001.jpg, cap_002.jpg etc)

Answer (score 3):

`ImageMagick` just relies on `ffmpeg` being installed. You can call that directly something like this:

```
/path/to/ffmpeg -y -pattern_type glob -i '/path/to/jpegs/*.jpg' -c:v libx264 -r 30 -crf 24 -s 1280x720 /path/to/destination/video.mpeg
```

I'm not sure how well that actually works on macOS, but it worked on our linux web server. `convert` is a good shortcut for it, though.

Comment: what does `-crf 24` do?

Answer (score 2):

I had a case where I had about 2500 pictures from a webcam I wanted to videoify. Both iMovie and the convert Script from ImageMagick couldn't handle the amount from file. There is a neat little program called ["Time Lapse Assembler"](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/33252/time-lapse-assembler) which did the trick. Beware: If you install, it tries to install some Yahoo-crap aswell

Comment: that's right! Had the same problem now on importing 4000 images. I also tried it with Adobe Lightroom, but it looks like even if you take parts of 1000 images it takes about 40 minutes on my mac book pro

Answer (score 2):

You can use QuickTimePlayer to easily create a time lapse.

Just use File > Open Image Sequence and select the images.

Details are here:
https://support.apple.com/guide/quicktime-player/create-a-movie-with-an-image-sequence-qtp315cce984/mac

Comment: Probably the easiest way to do it as of 2021, thank you. I could easily convert several thousand images into a video 

Answer (score 0):

This blog post solved it: https://nicholasnadeau.me/post/2020/5/converting-gopro-timelapse-to-a-video-or-gif-with-imagemagick-and-ffmpeg/

get them in order `ls | cat -n | while read n f; do mv "$f" "$n.jpg"; done`

`for F in $(find img -iname "*.jpg"); do convert $F -crop 4000x2250+0+375 out/$(basename $F); done`