# How to set up a time lapse capture for Samsung web cam SNH-P6410BN

Tags: webcam, recording

I am trying to create a time lapse with my webcam. it's a samsung SNH-P6410BN. The default software that it comes with has some very basic options. Are there any aftermarket software which could manage this camera and let me get into advanced capture? thank you

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of freeware software tools that can do this. Depending on your OS and webcam software, if you schedule it to take a snapshot every x minutes and store it in a directory, where the file name increments (00001.jpg, 00002.jpg, etc), you can then convert the series of JPEG files to a MPEG. [See this previous answer.](https://superuser.com/questions/404915/how-to-create-a-time-lapse-video-from-a-bunch-of-photos/404927#404927)

Answer (score 0):

I own the same camera, and, I too, was not happy with the software support provided.  I tried using the 'snapshot to Picasa' feature and was not satisfied.  I then realized that my Synology NAS provided a package called "Surveillance Station" that gave me much more capabilities.  These [include](https://www.synology.com/en-us/surveillance/6.3/spec)  a live view, multiple recording formats, and many more features I'm not using at the moment.  Using the NAS also provide me with a sense of privacy because I did not want to expose my captures to the public on a cloud system.  If you're willing to spend some money, using a NAS and associated software can give you what you want.

Comment: Thank you. As a matter of fact I do have a NAS. I was going just use an extra server to dedicate storing images and video on it. but i guess using a NAS would be more efficient.